# Powershell not processing beyond 1 entry in array. How can I make this work?

Tags: windows-10, download, powershell-ise

New to this. I have made the below script to download the newest versions of the applications and install them, but it only ever processes the first entry innosetup[0]

```
$inno ="https://downloads.avs4you.com/distributives/AVSInstallPack.exe::https://download.xnview.com/XnView-win-full.exe::https://download.xnview.com/XnViewMP-win-x64.exe::https://download.xnview.com/XnConvert-win-x64.exe::https://downloads.ntlite.com/files/NTLite_setup_x64.exe::https://www.kymoto.org/downloads/ISStudio_Latest.exe" -split "::"

foreach($dlfrom in $inno){
#selects the application from said list
    $dlfrom
#next section selects just the application name and creates the variable for the download destination
    $i= $dlfrom -split '/'
      foreach($_ in $i){
       if($_.Contains('.exe')){
       $dlto=$env:TEMP +'\'+ $_ }
}
#... and finally download the file
            invoke-webrequest $dlfrom -OutFile $dlto
}
```

It does https://downloads.avs4you.com/distributives/AVSInstallPack.exe and then stops, however when I just have it ECHO the results it processes the entire array.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out something that worked, but I don't know why it works!
A cleaner or clearer example would be greatly appreciated!

```
$inno ="https://downloads.avs4you.com/distributives/AVSInstallPack.exe::https://download.xnview.com/XnView-win-full.exe::https://download.xnview.com/XnViewMP-win-x64.exe::https://download.xnview.com/XnConvert-win-x64.exe::https://downloads.ntlite.com/files/NTLite_setup_x64.exe::https://www.kymoto.org/downloads/ISStudio_Latest.exe" -split "::"
foreach($dlfrom in $inno){
$dlfrom
$i= $dlfrom -split '/'
foreach($_ in $i){
if($_.Contains('.exe')){
$dlto=$env:TEMP +'\'+ $_ }
}
$dlto
invoke-webrequest $dlfrom -OutFile $dlto
}
```